# Adding Proportionate Na's in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe on lets say 3 columns and 20000 rows.

I want to add proportionate NA's i.e 20% of the random number of rows as NA in a **single column not in entire dataframe.**  .

But I have searched on stackoverflow and found how to add proportionate NA in a entire data frame.  and what I want is to add NA's in a single column.

Consider the below sample dataframe

```
    Customer    Date1   Date2
   51      13-08-2005   08-05-2007
   60      28-10-1992   11-01-2013
```

I have to add proportionate NA's in **Date2** column
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example with expected output?

Comment: by "add" do you mean replace 20% of elements with NAs? `df$var[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df) * .2)] <- NA` will do

Comment: @amatsuo_net yes exactly. I want to replace my 20% of rows by NA. But in a single column not in entire data frame.

Comment: Then `df$Date2[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df) * .2)] <- NA`

Comment: @amatsuo_net I have tried your code, but is said Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
invalid 'size' argument

Comment: @Sotos how should I validate this? whether I am getting the proportion as 80-20

Comment: you can do `sum(is.na(df$Date2))`

Comment: @Sotos Thanks It worked.....

Comment: @Manish, isn't it because your data.frame name is different than `df`?

Comment: @amatsuo_net, I have use appropriate data.frame name with your code. But it gave me that output

Comment: That's quite weird. An example like this works in my environment `library(dplyr);
df <- data.frame(Date2 = sample(1000, 100) %>% as.Date(origin = '2011-01-01'));
df$Date2[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df) * .2)] <- NA
`